# Sprite Action stops working after a period of time

Tags: sprite-kit

I have built a simple game in SpriteKit with a sound that plays every time the screen is tapped. It all works fine; however, after a varying period of time the action to play the sound stops and it says the following every time the screen is tapped;

2019-04-19 13:05:46.670138+0200 New Game[2559:608748] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "engine.mp3"

The game continues to work without the sound but after you complete the level you are on, the game crashes at the next transition as it says;

2019-04-19 13:05:47.044452+0200 New Game[2559:608748] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I remove the code for the engine sound action, it never crashes and the Optional for GScene! is never nil

If I remove the code for the engine sound action, it never crashes and the Optional is never nil

Sound Action:

```
//play engine sound
        let engineSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("engine.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
        self.run(engineSound)
```

Transition Code:

```
       GScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
       let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1)
       view?.presentScene(GScene!, transition: transition)
```

Comment: create engine sound once only, then just reuse it over and over.  Probably running out of buffer space when you keep opening it over and over

Comment: Thank you... sorted. I do this in a few places and I will rework it.